Strings .sort(key=?) function
I run a following code from the Python textbook:
strings = ['foo','card','bar','aaaa','abab']

strings.sort(key= lambda x : len(set(list(x))))

print(strings)

Out: ['aaaa', 'foo', 'abab', 'bar', 'card']
Why is the list sorted in this order?  It is neither due to number of letters, alphabetical order, nor ASCII codes.
In the book the explanation says that words are sorted taking into account number of letters in each word; yet this should place them in order from shortest to longest, which is not the case.

sets only contain unique elements. Also note list is unnecessary here, set('foo') -> {'f', 'o'} already.

This is sorting based on the number of unique letters in each string:
# number of unique letters
#   1      2      2       3      4
['aaaa', 'foo', 'abab', 'bar', 'card']

Here is a breakdown of the steps:

get letters (list) (this step is not needed, set(x) is enough)
find unique ones (set)
count them (len)

# strings
['foo','card','bar','aaaa','abab']

# sets: [set(x) for x in strings]
[{'f', 'o'}, {'a', 'c', 'd', 'r'}, {'a', 'b', 'r'}, {'a'}, {'a', 'b'}]

# lengths: [len(set(x)) for x in strings]
[2, 4, 3, 1, 2]


thank you, it's all clear to me now! :) Just to make sure: 'foo' and 'abab' both have the same number of unique letters (2), so each of them could be ranked either place 2 or place 3 in the sorted list? Or is there a reason 'foo' is being ranked as place 2?

Their relative positions depends on the algorithm that was used. In the case of list.sort, the algorithm is stable, this means that the original relative order of the input is maintained in case of a tie: 'foo' remains before 'abab'.

len(set(list(x))) is giving you the length of unique characters in list(x).
So "aaaa" has 1, "foo" and "abab" have 2, etc.
